# can't understand the steps of this differentation with different variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

In a modelling problem I set 2 new variables as  $\hat C=C/C_e$ and $\tau=kt$ in this differential equation $$ \dfrac {d}{dt}(C(t))=\lambda C_e-\lambda C(t)-kC(t)$$ in order to get this equation $$\dfrac {d}{dt}(\hat C(\tau))=(k/\lambda)(1-\hat C(\tau)) - \hat C(\tau).$$ I can't understand the steps we take in order to get from one equation to the other.

Comment: How comes you differentiate wrt $t$ when $ĉ$ depends on $\tau$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt} = k\frac{d}{d\tau}$$

Comment: Use `$\hat C$`, `$\lambda$`, `$\tau$` for the outputs $\hat C,\lambda, \tau$.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what i was looking for. Have a nice day!